# ColdFusion Write File

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I'm reading a simple file of logset.txt which only contains
Login:,Pass:

File is stored on webroot.

Reading it, and if no data after :.  I want user to set their login data and store it.

So they would enter on a form their login and password.
So enter Bob and Turkey

And then I want it to Overwrite the logset.txt file as: Login:Bob,Pass:Turkey

I am trying this with no luck.

```
<cfset nf = "Login:Bob,Pass:Turkey">

<CFFILE ACTION="Write"
    FILE="logset.txt"
    nameConflict="overwrite"
    OUTPUT="#nf#">
```

Is this a path issue? I have tried "/logset.txt" and "\logset.txt"

Comment: Your code should write the file in the directory where your cf template is present. Is the path of the cfm also on the webroot?

Comment: Please consider deleting the question if the answer does not serve any real purpose.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but passwords should not be stored in plain text

Answer (score 0):

Ignore.
Path Problem This works.

```
   <cfset fpath = expandpath('\')>

   <CFFILE ACTION="Write"
     FILE="#FPath#logset.txt"
     nameConflict="overwrite"
     OUTPUT="#nf#">
```

Now anyone got an idea of how to write to a mobile device local?

Comment: ColdFusion only writes on servers. It does not write on mobile devices.

Comment: To write to the user's device, use cookies.